# for each loop inside a if statement?

Tags: java

I've been getting an "illegal start of expression" error when trying to compile this `for` loop inside a `if` statement in java. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
if(letter.equals(" ") || letter == null ||for(String a: array){ letter.equals(a);})
```

Comment: A for loop doesn't evaluate to a boolean, so you can't put it in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
if( letter == null || letter.equals(" ") ||  checkArray(array, letter))
{
    ...
}


boolean checkArray(String[] arryay, String letter)
{
     for(String a: array) 
           if(letter.equals(a)) 
                return true;

     return false;
}
```

Note: checking letter for null after you have already called `equals()` does not make too much sense; i've reordered those.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Perhaps you should move the `if` statement into the `for` statement?

As `rfausak` said, a `for` statement does not return a boolean. You should have made that an answer by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that´s because you can not have a `for` loop within an `if` condition. It seems you want to see if the `letter` is within the `array` array; if so then you can do it with [Apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)'s [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html):

```
ArrayUtils.contains( array, letter );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Set you could write:

```
if ( (letter.equals(" ")) || (letter == null) || (a.contains(letter)) ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This wont work because a `for` doesn't evaluate to a boolean. For readabilities sake you should extract that to a method anyway, good examples appear in other answers.

Other points, you should rejig your conditionals to not be susceptible to `NullPointerException`s

```
if (letter == null || " ".equals(letter) || arrayContains(array, letter)) {
        //...
}
```

If you are able to add additional libraries, there are some nice apache commons libraries to make this work easier, namely [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) in commons-lang and [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) in commons-collections.

You also may like to harden that input checking if it's possible to get `String`s larger than one character, by using `String#trim()` after checking for `null`. Again, this would be a good candidate for an extracted method `isBlank(String str)`.